# How do I plot a SymPy function which is depending on two variables?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, sympy

So I am trying to implement the following function [Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fisGX.png), which should result in this plot: [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZjRd.png).
w, l, δ are constants in general, but the function `C_EF` has `w/δ` as argument so I implemented `w/δ` using SymPy.

To cope with the sums from 0 to Inf, I used while loops checking for a small enough increment between steps to stop the sums.
However, with my overall implementation I can't quite get the same plot as in the graph included.
I am not sure where my code is wrong, but I am thinking about, that the function depending on `δ^2` and `w` also next to `w/δ` could lead to the problems.
EDIT: The following screenshot shows the resulting plot from my code: [My Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l05Q.png)

```
### IMPORTS AND ABBREVATIONS ###
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy
from sympy import *  # plot, re, im, symbols, I
import sympy as sym

mu_r = 1.05  # Relative permeability
mu_0 = 4 * pi * 10 ** -7  # magnetic permeability of free space
mu = mu_0 * mu_r  # H/m; Absolute permeability
sigma = 7.1 * 10 ** 5  # S/m; Electrical conductivity für NdFeB Magnet
f = 2500  # Hz; carrier Frequency
B_h_s = 1.5  # T; peak Flux density

dAG = 2.5 * 10 ** -3  
w_magnet = 60 * 10 ** -3  
h = 5 * 10 ** -3  
l = 3*w_magnet  
pi = scipy.pi

wd = Symbol('wd')

def P_calc(w):
    dlt = (sym.sqrt(1 / (pi * mu * sigma * f)) * sym.sqrt((h + dAG) / h)).evalf()

    # (11) Sums
    def nth_term(a, n_sum):
        lmd_n = (2 * n_sum + 1) * pi / w 
        beta_n = sym.sqrt(lmd_n ** 2 + 2 * I / (dlt ** 2)) 
        if a == 1:
            return ((lmd_n ** 2 - 2 * im(beta_n) ** 2) * re(beta_n) * lmd_n ** 3 * sym.sinh(re(beta_n) * l)) / \
                   ((2 * n_sum + 1) ** 5 * abs(beta_n) ** 6 * (sym.cosh(re(beta_n) * l) + sym.cos(im(beta_n) * l)))
        elif a == 2:
            return ((lmd_n ** 2 + 2 * re(beta_n) ** 2) * im(beta_n) * lmd_n ** 3 * sym.sin(im(beta_n) * l)) / \
                   ((2 * n_sum + 1) ** 5 * abs(beta_n) ** 6 * (sym.cosh(re(beta_n) * l) + sym.cos(im(beta_n) * l)))

    tolerance = 1e-6
    max_iterations = 1000
    sum_1_C_EF = 0
    n = 0
    while True:
        term_1 = nth_term(1, n)
        sum_1_C_EF += term_1
        n += 1
        # Check convergence criteria
        if math.fabs(term_1) < tolerance or n >= max_iterations:
            break

    sum_2_C_EF = 0
    n = 0
    while True:
        term_2 = nth_term(2, n)
        sum_2_C_EF += term_2
        n += 1
        # Check convergence criteria
        if math.fabs(term_2) < tolerance or n >= max_iterations:
            break

    sum_C_EF = sum_1_C_EF + sum_2_C_EF
    C_EF_sinh_cosh = ((sym.cosh(wd) + sym.cos(wd)) / (sym.sinh(wd) - sym.sin(wd)))
    C_EF_term = ((32 * w) / ((pi ** 5) * l)) * (wd ** 3)

    # (11) complete
    C_EF = 1 - C_EF_term * C_EF_sinh_cosh * sum_C_EF

    p = plot(C_EF, (wd, 0, 6), ylabel='C_EF', line_color='b', show=False)
    p.show()

    return P_e

P_e = P_calc(w_magnet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task I wouldn't use SymPy, because the `re` and `im` functions are going to apply simplifications that actually makes the expression extremely long, hence difficult to compute. We can use NumPy for this task.

This is how I would set up the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu_r = 1.05  # Relative permeability
mu_0 = 4 * np.pi * 10 ** -7  # magnetic permeability of free space
mu = mu_0 * mu_r  # H/m; Absolute permeability
sigma = 7.1 * 10 ** 5  # S/m; Electrical conductivity für NdFeB Magnet
f = 2500  # Hz; carrier Frequency
B_h_s = 1.5  # T; peak Flux density

dAG = 2.5 * 10 ** -3  
h = 5 * 10 ** -3 
w_magnet = 60 * 10 ** -3  
delta = np.sqrt(1 / (np.pi * mu * sigma * f)) * np.sqrt((h + dAG) / h)
w = w_magnet

# break down pieces for easy of coding and reading
lam = lambda n: (2 * n + 1) * np.pi / w
beta = lambda n: np.sqrt(lam(n)**2 + 2j / delta**2)
beta_r = lambda n: np.real(beta(n))
beta_i = lambda n: np.imag(beta(n))
den = lambda l, n: (2 * n + 1)**5 * np.absolute(beta(n))**6 * (np.cosh(np.float128(beta_r(n) * l)) + np.cos(beta_i(n) * l))

def s1(l, N):
    s = lambda n: (lam(n)**2 - 2 * beta_i(n)**2) * beta_r(n) * lam(n)**3 * np.sinh(np.float128(beta_r(n) * l)) / den(l, n)
    return sum(s(n) for n in range(N + 1))

def s2(l, N):
    s = lambda n: (lam(n)**2 + 2 * beta_r(n)**2) * beta_i(n) * lam(n)**3 * np.sin(beta_i(n) * l) / den(l, n)
    return sum(s(n) for n in range(N + 1))

# sum up to N
N = 100
t1 = lambda l: (32 * w / (np.pi**5 * l))
t2 = lambda w_d: (np.cosh(w_d) + np.cos(w_d)) / (np.sinh(w_d) - np.sin(w_d))
t3 = lambda l: s1(l, N) + s2(l, N)
C_EF = lambda w_d, l: 1 - w_d**3 * t1(l) * t2(w_d) * t3(l)

C_EF = np.vectorize(C_EF)
w_d = np.linspace(0, 6, 10)

plt.figure()
for m in [1, 1.5, 3, 8]:
    plt.plot(w_d, C_EF(w_d, m * w), label=r"$l = %s \cdot w$" % m)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Clearly, this is not the graph you are looking for. I've double checked the formula with what I typed: to my eyes they appear to be identical...

Notes:

1. Instead of summing up to infinity, I sum up to N=100. That's up to you to decide. I've also tried N=5 and the result doesn't appear to change that much.
2. I casted the arguments of `np.sinh` and `np.cosh` to `np.float128` because for relatively large n, the results of those terms wouldn't fit into a regular float64.

Comment: Thanks very much! Very confusing for me how they got the plot they show... But I have some questions left: Is `np.longdouble` also suitable instead of `np.float128`? Also, I get multiple RunTime Warnings with your implementation, is this intended?

Comment: According to Numpy documentation, `np.float128` provides only as much precision as `np.longdouble`, so the latter should also be suitable for this computation. The runtime warning are due to the fact the `w_d` has been discretized from the the value 0: the `C_EF` expressions has `(np.sinh(w_d) - np.sin(w_d))` at denominator. When `w_d=0`, you get a division by zero, hence the Runtime warning. You can start `w_d` from some small number, like 0.001 or less, and the runtime warning should disappear.

Comment: I still cant wrap my head around it how they achieved that `np.tanh`-looking function. I must be missing something, maybe that besides the arguement `w_d`, which equals to `w/δ` in the original equation, `beta` also depends on `δ`? So on the one hand I vary  `w/δ` by using it as the function's argument, and on the other hand I tie `δ` to a constant in `beta`?

Comment: I'm afraid that's for you to figure it out as I don't know the physics of your problem...